# C Convert decimal scanf input to binary array

Tags: c, raspberry-pi

I am working on a program to get my RaspPi to drive an old HP hexadecimal dispay.   I currently Im using a case/switch option to control the GPIO output selection.  I want to use direct binary input.  How can I convert the decimal scanf() input to a binary array?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>


int main()
{

 int displayNumber;

  wiringPiSetup();

  pinMode(0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(0, LOW);
  digitalWrite(1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(6, LOW);

    printf("Please select a number to display! 0-9\n");

    scanf("%i", &displayNumber);


   switch (displayNumber) {

    case 0:
    digitalWrite(6, LOW);
    digitalWrite(3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(0, LOW);
    digitalWrite(1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(6, HIGH);
    break;

    case 1:
    digitalWrite(6, LOW);
    digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(0, LOW);
    digitalWrite(1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(6, HIGH);
    break;

    case 2:
    digitalWrite(6, LOW);
    digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(0, LOW);
    digitalWrite(1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(6, HIGH);
    // code
    break;

    case 3:
    digitalWrite(6, LOW);
    digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(0, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(6, HIGH);
    // Code
    break;

    case 4:
    digitalWrite(6, LOW);
    digitalWrite(3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(0, LOW);
    digitalWrite(1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(6, HIGH);

    break;

    case 5:
    digitalWrite(6, LOW);
    digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(0, LOW);
    digitalWrite(1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(6, HIGH);

    break;

    case 6:
    digitalWrite(6, LOW);
    digitalWrite(3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(0, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(6, HIGH);

    break;
    case 7:
    digitalWrite(6, LOW);
    digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(0, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(6, HIGH);

    break;
    case 8:
    digitalWrite(6, LOW);
    digitalWrite(3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(0, LOW);
    digitalWrite(1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(6, HIGH);

    break;
    case 9:
    digitalWrite(6, LOW);
    digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(0, LOW);
    digitalWrite(1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(6, LOW);
    break;
    }



return 0;

}
```

Comment: show your progress, where are you stuck?

Comment: I can change the HIGH and LOW options to 1 and 0 respectively,  Sorry for not adding the code initially.

Comment: By `Convert decimal to binary`, do you mean send the binary pattern of the number you scan to the output pins?

Comment: Yes, right now I I have hard coded in the binary versions of each allowed input(I know this is incomplete as I have not locked out other inputs)  I am looking at a way to have the program compute each binary 1/0 to shorten up the code.  BTW pin 6 is a display input lock thats why it never changes.

Comment: What is the first argument to `digitalWrite`?

Comment: It comes from the wiringPi library.  Its a short cut to the address of the RasPi GPIO address.  the general format for it is digitalWrite(pin, value);

Comment: I am not familiar with RasPi, but your hardcoding of the outputs doesn't seem to match the binary patterns of the numbers in the case statement (excluding pin6)

Comment: In the case statements the pin assignments(the digit) repersents the particular pin number(using the wiringPi scheme) the value(HIGH/LOW) can be replaced with 1/0 respectivly.  Its the HIGHT/LOW thats the binary part.

Comment: Slightly OT, but your current setup will generate a very short write pulse on pin 6, which will only be as long as it takes to write the values to pins 0..3.  The shortness of this duration may/may not cause an issue with your HP display depending on your wiring and HP specs.

Comment: `case 1:` does the same as `case 2:`

Comment: @PeterM the state change on pin 6 is to unlock the display and then puts it back to high after the change to update the display, The code actually works, I was just wanting to get a more flexable code.

Comment: "code actually works" ?? `case 9:` never sets `digitalWrite(6, HIGH);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the solution for you, there is no need for an array since you can directly write the bits

```
int main()
{
    int displayNumber;
    int pins[6] = {3, 0, 1, 2};
    int i;

    wiringPiSetup();

    pinMode(0, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(6, OUTPUT);

    digitalWrite(0, LOW);
    digitalWrite(1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(6, LOW);

    displayNumber = -1;
    while ((displayNumber < 0) || (displayNumber > 9))
    {
        printf("Please select a number to display! 0-9\n");
        scanf("%i", &displayNumber);
    }

    digitalWrite(6, LOW);
    for (i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++)
        digitalWrite(pins[i], displayNumber & (1 << i) ? HIGH : LOW);
    digitalWrite(6, HIGH);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it did not change state of the GPIO which is needed to effect the display.

Comment: @NicholasRice i was confused, you should never say thanks, not even when it helped, thats what accepet is for. So I was confused with, thanks. How should the bits be set? show an example in your question, I mean which pin should be HIGH and which one should be LOW when?

Comment: My apology for the confusion,  EX. if the user inputs 2 I am looking for the system to convert the 2 decimal number to 0010.  HIGH(or 1) means the GPIO is sending 3.3V  a LOW(or 0) means the GPIO sending 0V

Comment: I can see that, I'm not confused about that, it's just that in `0010` which pins should be HIGH and which pins should be LOW?

Comment: ok, in the case of 0010, the pins should be as follows. {3-LOW, 0-HIGH, 1-LOW, 2-LOW}. I realize my code has that error in it.

Comment: Correction to my previous comment( I found a disconnected lead on bread board) the code you provided does change the Display, but not in corrct sequence. the following is the Input/output details.  0/0, 1/0, 2/8, 3/8, 4/4, 5/4, 6/C, 7/C, 8/2, 9/2

Comment: The 6 pin is the input latch, it goes LOW to allow input change, then HIGH to implement the change.

Comment: bit better, now its 0/0,1/0,2/1,3/1, 4/2,5/2,6/3,7/3,8/4,9/4.  I will do some more checks, I accept your answer and will build upon it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Replace switch statements with

```
digitalWrite(6, LOW);
digitalWrite(3, displayNumber & 1 ? HIGH : LOW);
digitalWrite(0, displayNumber & 2 ? HIGH : LOW);
digitalWrite(1, displayNumber & 4 ? HIGH : LOW);
digitalWrite(2, displayNumber & 8 ? HIGH : LOW);
digitalWrite(6, HIGH);
```

Answer (score 0):

Read this article:

[C Program to Convert Decimal to Binary](https://www.udemy.com/blog/c-programs-to-convert-decimal-to-binary/)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
  int d[20];
  int decimalno,i=0;
  printf("Enter the decimal number you want to conver to binary: \n");
  scanf("%d",&decimalno);
  while(decimalno>0)
  {
       d[i]=decimalno%2;
       i++;
       decimalno=decimalno/2;
  }
  printf("The binary version of the number you input, %d, is = ",decimalno);
  for(int j=i-1;j>=0;j--)
  {
        printf("%d",d[j]);
  }
  //getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: shouldn't the printf come before the second for loop?

Comment: And this is a very inefficient algorithm. `d` should be `char d[CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int) + 1 /* +1 for trailing '\0' */ ]` or else the bits could be more than the `char`s and you should use the `&` and `>>` operators instead of `%` and `/`. And if you null terminate the array you can just `printf("%s\n", d);`